# Can we write python automation code for opening different url in each time, modifying the previous url?

Tags: python, selenium, automation

For example -

Iteration 1 = https://australiapopulation.com/lucifer-season-1-subtitles/

Iteration 2 = https://australiapopulation.com/lucifer-season-2-subtitles/

Iteration 3 = https://australiapopulation.com/lucifer-season-3-subtitles/

Comment: what exactly you wanna do with the mentioned URL's  ?

Comment: Just open them in different tabs, nothing else.

Comment: Okay, check out the answers below. Should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Example provided is written in Java, but it won't be a problem to write it in Python.

Firstly, you need to store your URLs in a List or Array at least.
Then open tabs by JS executor and loop through them:

```
String[] relativeUrls = {"url_1", "url_2", "url_3"};
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver; // this is your driver object


ArrayList<String> tabs = new ArrayList<String>(driver.getWindowHandles());

for (int i = 0; i < relativeUrls.size(); i++) {
  jse.executeScript("window.open()");
  driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(1));
  driver.navigate().to(driver.getCurrentUrl() + relativeUrls[i]);
  driver.close();
}
```

Comment: Actually this www.link.com/TRP00213/, www.link.com/BRP0021/, Something which can take the number after / automatically, let's say we can prepare a list of 5 such unique numbers list = [TRP0001, PRO3215, QWS4569, TYR4569, ASD6548], Now I want the URL to be the same that is www.link.com, for once the URL which will should open is www.link.com/TRP0001/ second should be www.link.com/PRO3215/ and so on. Just want to append unique numbers with the link so that it opens a specific file in every tab. And i'm not willing to give full links just the unique number in a list that is TRP0001.

Answer (score 0):

store all the links in a list like below, then have a `loop` and inside just open a link using `driver.get()`, all you have to make sure is that, keep the `current window handle` (which will be unique for every window) and then `switch to` it

You can do this :

```
links = ["https://australiapopulation.com/lucifer-season-1-subtitles/", "https://australiapopulation.com/lucifer-season-2-subtitles/", "https://australiapopulation.com/lucifer-season-3-subtitles/"]
number_of_tabs = len(links)
count = 1
for link in links :
  driver.get(link)
  windows_before = driver.current_window_handle
  driver.execute_script("window.open('');")
  #WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.number_of_windows_to_be(number_of_tabs))
  new_window = driver.window_handles[count]
  count = count + 1
  driver.switch_to.window(new_window)
  sleep(3)
```

Comment: Actually what I'm trying to do is not to counter in sequence, I just want to modify the link like www.link.com/TRP00213/, www.link.com/BRP0021/, www.link.com/VRT001213/. The url will be the same, I just want to modify it so that it opens different pages in different tabs

Comment: Something which can take the number after / automatically, let's say we can prepare a list of 5 such unique numbers list = [TRP0001, PRO3215, QWS4569, TYR4569, ASD6548], Now I want the URL to be the same that is www.link.com, for once the URL which will should open is www.link.com/TRP0001/ second should be www.link.com/PRO3215/ and so on. Just want to append unique numbers with the link so that it opens a specific file in every tab. And i'm not willing to give full links just the unique number in a list that is TRP0001.